# How can i control the multiple users accessing the same database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am making my first project using `vb.net` and `access`. I am trying to develop a project in which the data of patients of the is added from different counters. what I developed is working fine when only one counter adds data in database but when two counters access the same database and try to save the record it gives error primary key can not be duplicate.

I doing what, first I am generating a primary key number i.e. patient no that is unique to every patient. patient no. is one increment to the last saved record. then the user enter (counter data entry operator) adds the patient details and then hit the save button.

In multi-user environment both the operators generate the same patient no. when they hit the new record button as both see the same last saved record. while saving the record one operator save the record successfully but other operator get the duplicate primary key error.

Pessimistic and optimistic locks are not working for me or i am not understanding how to use them.

```
rsS As New ADODB.Recordset
rsS.Open(str, conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)
```

What I have tried:

I also tried to solve this problem by saving the patient no. in another variable `oldPatientno` and beore saving the record checked if there is any change in the database if so then regenerate the patient no. but this is not working.

Comment: You should let the database generate the IDs for you.  In Access, that's what the `AutoNumber` data type is for.

Comment: Whether or not it is the primary key, you are trying to generate a unique identifier that has meaning to users. This is a common topic. I accomplish this by generating the number and immediately committing record to the table. User enters remaining data for that record and another user can create the next identifier. The chance of two users generating the same number, although not impossible, is greatly reduced. I've never had duplication error.

Comment: As @jmcilhinney suggested, you'll get around this issue by using `AutoNumber` data type on your ID column, rather than setting in programmatically. Is the primary key a composite key? Is there another field which has to be unique?